# Cómo mostrar imagen según referer con PHP en blogspot

Tags: referer

Quiero mostrar una imagen en base al referer del visitante, ejemplo

```
<img src="https://web.com/image.php">
```

Si la visita es de facebook, que se vea la imagen 1.jpg y si no, que se vea la imagen 2.jpg

Este código lo usaré en Blogspot, alguien me podría dar alguna idea por favor.

Gracias.

He avanzado con esto

```
<?php
// Cargamos la imagen a mostrar
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$web = "facebook.com";
if(strpos($referer , $web)){   
         $archivo='v.jpg';
}else{
         $archivo='ws.jpg';
}
header("Content-type: image/jpg");
header("Content-length: ".filesize($archivo));
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$archivo");

readfile($archivo);

?>
```

Funciona bien si entro a web.com/file.php desde facebook (muestra v.jpg)

Pero cuando lo pego en blogspot como

```
<img src="https://web.com/file.php">
```

No reconoce el referer de facebook (muestra ws.jpg al ingresar desde Ffacebook ), cómo puedo solucionarlo?

GRACIAS.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro, pero puedes probar con algo asi

```html
<img src="<?php echo $imagen;?>">
<?php 
 $anterior = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
 if (echo $anterior == "facebook"){
    $imagen = "img/img1.png";
  }
  else{
    $imagen = "img/img2.png";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Pero este código no lo puedo pegar en blogspot. :(

Comment: No puedes añadir php? Javascript puedes?